Better way to concat many files other than tail?
I would like to concat all files of a certain type in a directory sans the first two lines in each file.
I tried tail -n +3 path/to/files/foo_bar_* >> BigDataFile.dat
However, the BigDataFile.dat looks like this:
path/to/files/foo_bar_1.txt
data1   
data2  
data3  

path/to/files/foo_bar_2.txt
data1  
data2  
data3
etc…

Can I get tell tail to not insert the comment with the path and file name and the extra line? Or should I use a different method?
Cat would work great, but I haven't figured out a good way of not including the first two lines in the file.

tail has a -q option to suppress printing of headers when multiple files are being processed.

Ah! That seems way more obvious than I thought! Thanks!

Another way using Awk (although I suppose it'd be slower than using tail):
awk 'FNR>2' file*

Which basically means: if the current record number (of the current file) is greater than 2 (which by default means: "if the current line number is greater than 2"), print the line.
% cat file1
f1line1
f1line2
f1line3
% cat file2
f2line1
f2line2
f2line3
% awk 'FNR>2' file*
f1line3
f2line3

